# SVG mask to work with android

Tags: javascript, android, html, css, svg

I am having trouble with my SVG mask on an Android device it give a square block when it is meant to be transparent

```
<svg width="0" height="0">
     <mask id="mask">
        <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" stroke="#ff0000" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-width="4" d="M 34 2 c 11.6 0 21.8 6.2 27.4 15.5 c 2.9 4.8 5 16.5 -9.4 16.5 h -4"></path>
     </mask>
</svg>
```

Here is a codepen of the complete code [codepen](http://codepen.io/daniel152/pen/gpoKRJ)

Thanks in advance.

**** UPDATE ******

[image: pic 1 when normal]
[image: pic 2 when on a android device]

The pic on the left is on a iPhone the one on the right is a android.

You will be able to see what I mean if you use the chrome device inspect manager and select galaxy s4. Unfortunately, I cant reduce the code as its all part of it.

The square is cased by the snippet of code above which is in the HTML file, it is ment to be a SVG mask.

Comment: Please add more information. What square block? Where?  Can you reduce your code to something minimal that shows the problem?

Comment: Hi Paul, i tried my best to update above

Comment: I am seeing that block in Chrome also.  Please reduce your sample to something short (eg. just the hamburger).

Comment: Hi Paul, i reduced it as much as possible http://codepen.io/daniel152/pen/gpoKRJ i hope this is ok

Comment: ok i solved this by creating my mask as a png, the problem i have now is not being able to prevent it playing on page load